# Oracle PHP update no response

Tags: php, oracle, sql-update, no-response

I got a very weird problem with oracle today.

I setup a new server with xampp for developing, i activated mssql and oracle and everything was just fine until i tried to execute an update statement.

Every select, insert, etc is working fine with PHP 5.3.

I also can parse the statement and get a ressource id back, but when i try to execute the statement my whole site is not responding.

no error, nothing. just timeout until i restart the apache.

here the code... it's the test code, so there should be no problem at all.

```
$conn = oci_connect('***', '***', '***');

$query ="UPDATE CHAR*** SET TPOS = 14, ID = 5, DIFF = 'J' WHERE ***NR = '3092308' AND LA*** = '5'";
echo $query;
echo '<br>';
echo $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);    
oci_free_statement($stid2);
```

Any hints or ideas? :-(
I already tried to reinstall the oracle instant client and another version. I am using 10g like our db at the moment.

best regards
pad

Comment: If you look in the database, is the session blocked?  Perhaps you're trying to update a row that is locked by some other session?  Can you `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the row in question?

Comment: Perhaps you should call `oci_commit()` after a write-type query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row may be [locked by another session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172378/oracle-update-hangs/1172526#1172526). If this is the case, your session will hang until the other transaction ends (commit/rollback).

You should do a [`SELECT FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2066346) before attempting to update a row (pessimistic locking):

- If the row is locked, you will get an error and can return a message to the user that this record is currently being updated by another session. In most cases an explicit message is preferable to indefinite waiting.
- If the row is available, you will make sure no session modifies its content until you commit (and thus you will prevent any form of [lost update](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:30562552526857)).

There are other reasons why a simple update may take a long time but they are less likely, for instance:

- When you update an [unindexed foreign key](http://tkyte.blogspot.fr/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteunindex.html), Oracle needs to acquire a lock on the whole parent table for a short time. This may take a long time on a busy and/or large table.
- There could be triggers on the table that perform additional work.

For further reading: [pessimistic vs optimistic locking](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5771117722373).

Comment: yes you were right. i got the ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT error, so some other statement (most likely mine from before with no commit) blocks the table

Comment: @pad maybe this is due to a previous attempt that has not commited and still hangs around idly. You can query `V$SESSION` to gather information and eventually kill the blocking transactions. The blocked session should be `ACTIVE` in this view and the blocking session should be showed in the `BLOCKING_SESSION` column.

Comment: thanks a lot. my problem is solved. i terminated the open session. :)