# Dapper Hangs at Execute

Tags: c#, json, database, dapper, idbconnection

I have an
- IDbConnection
- sql = @"UPDATE tablename SET json = :json, lastupdate = SYSDATE WHERE id = :id"

```
var param = new DynamicParameters();
param.Add(":json", json, DbType.AnsiString);
param.Add(":id", currentTemplate.Id);

if (connection == null || connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) continue;
connection.Execute(sql, param);  // hangs here.
connection.Query(sql, param);  // tried this and this also hangs.
```

**Coding stops at connection.Execute.  No error or anything.  Just hangs.**

:json is a serialized object returned by JsonConvert.

:id is a string

I've also tried removing the parameters and including the values in the SQL itself.

Comment: does the same thing work via ADO.NET directly? is `json` actually a `string`?

Comment: I hadn't tried ADO.  Yes, the JSON was just a string.

Once I tried it at work, it functioned properly.  I'm still curious why this happened!

Comment: I'm tempted to say: a problem inside idbconnecton, perhaps relating to connectivity; dapper doesn't do anything particularly exciting here

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had an uncommitted transaction in another session, as described here: [Oracle Update Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172378/oracle-update-hangs)