# Dapper type mapping hangs in Windows 10 for large queries

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, dapper, windows-10

I have a very simply query in my projects that returns ~1.3 million rows:

```
var aliases = ctx.Query<sec_entity_alias>(@"select * from sec_entity_alias");
```

The class that is mapped to is:

```
    public partial class sec_entity_alias
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int sec_entity_id { get; set; }
    public byte sec_entity_alias_type_id { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }

    public virtual sec_entity_alias_type sec_entity_alias_type { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the query it hangs indefinitely and pegs the CPU.
When I remove the dapper type mapping and instead run the following, the query returns all rows in ~200ms

```
var aliases = ctx.Query(@"select * from sec_entity_alias");
```

This issue suddenly started appearing today after I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1

Has anyone else noticed this issue or am I missing something apparent here?

**EDIT:**

I just ran the same code on a Windows'12 R2 server and it ran completely fine.

Below is a profiling session where spends the most time on the Windows 10 machine.

Another interesting tidbit: when I create a new project and only query the sec_entity_alias table it works fine but in my main project where I load some other tables first is where it encounters the issue.

[image]

Comment: Interesting stuff !!!

Comment: That is interesting and alarming. I haven't updated my workstation to win 10 yet, but: I am intrigued! I am not aware of any reason why this might be the case.

Comment: It seems to become a problem at around 500k records - when I reduce the records to 400k the query is fast and when I have 500k records it hangs indefinitely.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am having the exact same issue with Dapper, queries hanging indefinitely. In my case it is on both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012, so not related to the OS. It has happened maybe 5 times since I switched from NPoco to Dapper, using the same queries. Although I can't pinpoint it exactly, it also seems to occur on queries with a huge number of returned results. I have also seen this even older post which mentions a similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029951/dapper-hangs-at-execute

Comment: @MarcGravell: It does not seem to concern large queries only. The only one I've caught while debugging was a query that returns 424 rows. After hanging indefinitely and re-executing, the issue does not appear again.  The execution was: `return _db.Query<MyModel>(sqlString).ToList();`. The logs show the following data: from the all 311 executions (hour by hour) of my process, 4 failed because of this error (30min timeout instead of average 5 second execution). 3 of those failures where during the last 24h.

Comment: @XavierPeña this is ... odd; sounds like some kind of nasty deadlock case; are you using the sync API or the async API? (just to give me a foot in)

Comment: @MarcGravell I am using the sync API: `<package id="Dapper" version="1.50.2" targetFramework="net452" />`. I will try to find more hints that might help track this problem, I'll post them here right away if there were any.

Comment: @MarcGravell I am trying to track it down with the following strategy: [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40017402/831138). Two more timeouts occurred during the night. It is also worth noting that I am using `MySql.Data` as a connector.

Comment: fyi, I was able to resolve this with setting "buffered:false" in the query